# Return all orders in mult-tenant api in different database

Tags: laravel, api, multi-tenant

I'm building a mult-tenant api in laravel. All tables are stored in each tenant's database. But the table of companies (tenant) and users is in a central database.

It turns out that now I need to return all sales for a given user. But, they are spread over several DBs.

Is there any solution to return all sales considering this scenario?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows.

I return all master companies, do a foreach on each connection in the company's database, return all sales and include it in a new array. In the end I order them all with collect and return only the values.
Below is the full code:

```
$databaseName = DB::connection('main')->getDatabaseName();
$user = Auth::user();

$companies = Company::where('idParent', null)->get()->makeVisible(['databaseName']);

$orders = array();

foreach ($companies as $company) {
    CompanyConnector::reconnect($company->databaseName);

    $orderModel = new Order();
    $orderByTenant = $orderModel->withoutGlobalScope(TenantScope::class)->with('items')
            ->join($databaseName.'.users as user', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'user.id' )
            ->join($databaseName.'.companies as company', 'orders.tenant_id', '=', 'company.id' )
            ->select(['orders.*', 'user.name', 'company.fantasyName as fantasyName'])
            ->where('customer_id', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('orders.id', 'desc')
            ->take(15)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

    $orders = array_merge($orders, $orderByTenant);
}

$orders = collect($orders)->sortByDesc('created_at')->values();

return $orders;
```